# Syntax for joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, join

I need to query for rows from 3 different tables based upon certain `WHERE` criteria.

My tables are:

- regions
- profiles
- usermeta

The profiles table has two foreign keys, user_id and region_id which reference the following tables.

The users table has an id, first_name and last_name column. I need to get the first_name and last_name for each row that has an id in the profiles table as well.

The regions table has a name and id column. I need to get the name for each region that has a corresponding id in the profiles table.

Out of the profiles table, I also have columns id, certs, and title which I need.

Right now I'm pulling these with three separate queries which is so inefficient. I know I can do it with JOINS, but I'm not sure what the syntax is supposed to be.

UPDATE:

After a lot of help from you guys and doing some additional digging, here is the right code for the query in PHP and WordPress formats:

```
    $select_sql = "SELECT p.id, p.title, concat( u1.meta_value, ' ', u2.meta_value ) as fullname, concat( r.name, ', ', c.name ) as location";
    $from_sql   = "FROM {$modules->tables->profiles} p";
    $join_sql   = "LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} u1 ON p.user_id = u1.user_id AND u1.meta_key = 'first_name'";
    $join_sql  .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} u2 ON p.user_id = u2.user_id AND u2.meta_key = 'last_name'";
    $join_sql  .= " LEFT JOIN {$modules->tables->regions} r ON r.id = p.region_id";
    $join_sql  .= " LEFT JOIN {$modules->tables->countries} c ON c.id = p.country_id";
    $where_sql  = "WHERE p.certification IN ( '%s' ) AND p.country_id IN ( %d )";
    $orderby_sql= "ORDER BY p.user_id ASC";

    $q = $wpdb->prepare( "{$select_sql} {$from_sql} {$join_sql} {$where_sql} {$orderby_sql}", $certification, $country_id );
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $q );
```

A var_dump on $q gives us the following SQL:

```
string(515) "SELECT p.id, p.title, concat( u1.meta_value, ' ', u2.meta_value ) as fullname, concat( r.name, ', ', c.name ) as location FROM modules_profiles p LEFT JOIN moonlight_usermeta u1 ON p.user_id = u1.user_id AND u1.meta_key = 'first_name' LEFT JOIN moonlight_usermeta u2 ON p.user_id = u2.user_id AND u2.meta_key = 'last_name' LEFT JOIN modules_regions r ON r.id = p.region_id LEFT JOIN modules_countries c ON c.id = p.country_id WHERE p.certification IN ( 'certified' ) AND p.country_id IN ( 2 ) ORDER BY p.user_id ASC"
```

Comment: Syntax for multiple `JOIN`s is no different than just for one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `JOIN` between all the tables. Below query is the assemble of the information provided by you in posts

```
select users.first_name,
users.last_name,
regions.name,
profiles.id, 
profiles.certs, 
profiles.title
from users 
left join profiles on profiles.user_id = users.id
left join region on profiles.region_id = regions.id;
```

Comment: I added the new sql to my question above.  I have it working without usermeta, but as soon as I put that table into the mix, nothing gets returned.

Comment: @TonyaLUNARWP, in that case do a `LEFT JOIN` instead like `LEFT JOIN moonlight_usermeta u ON u.user_id = p.user_id`. something like in my edited answer.

Comment: No dice.  u.first_name and u.last_name is not in any of the other database tables than usermeta.  And r.name is only in regions.

Comment: @TonyaLUNARWP, you were getting an empty set cause you were doing an `inner join` which gives only matched result. If not match then you get empty result and so you need to go for a outer join like left/right outer join.

Comment: I changed both JOIN to LEFT JOIN and still am only getting empty results.

Comment: @TonyaLUNARWP,in that case check your WHERE condition. Does rows with that filter really exists in table? Can't help further without seeing sample data from all tables involved in query.

Comment: use those columns do exist in the profiles table.  When I remove LEFT JOIN moonlight_usermeta from the sql, I get the right results by pulling from profiles and regions using the WHERE statement.

Comment: thank you for your help.  I was actually not targeting the right columns in usermeta.  After a little digging, I found the right SQL for that portion.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a join looks something like this:

```
SELECT stuff
FROM firstTable
JOIN secondTable ON firstTable.someColumn = secondTable.matchingColumn
```

In this case, I also recommend using table aliases (just adding an alias right after the table name is enough). This is just a simple push in the right direction:

```
SELECT columnsYouNeed
FROM users u
JOIN profiles p ON p.user_id = u.id
JOIN regions r ON r.id = p.region_id;
```

This is the syntax you are looking for, I'll challenge you to input the columns properly and add any WHERE clause you might need. If you are still stuck, feel free to ask questions.

Comment: @McAdmin331 I added the new sql to my question above.  I have it working without usermeta, but as soon as I put that table into the mix, nothing gets returned.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated by using JOINs

Below is a query based on the assumption that a user may to necessarily have a profile or a region.

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name, regions.name,  profiles.id, profiles.certs, profiles.title
FROM users
LEFT JOIN profiles ON profiles.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN regions ON regions.id = profiles.region_id
```

If they always do have that, or you only want those with profiles and regions then you could change it to a INNER JOIN

Comment: I added the new sql to my question above.  I have it working without usermeta, but as soon as I put that table into the mix, nothing gets returned.